# C++ Сдвиг курсора в бинарном файле в любое место при помощи seekp и перезапись только одного элемента

Tags: c++

Я новичок  в программировании. Создаю бинарный файл, заполняю его, хочу сдвинуть курсор при помощи seekp(_j * sizeof(int), ios::beg);. Курсор сдвигается на нужную позицию (_j), но пройденные элементы перезаписывает в 0. Например элементы файла: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Нужно вместо 4 записать 8. При помощи seekp курсор сдвигается на нужную позицию, но оставляет после себя 0, 0, 0, 8, 5. Долго гуглил, везде говорится что st3.seekp(_j * sizeof(int), ios::beg); это правильный вариант для С++.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


void find(int _m[], int _j)


{

    int t;

    cout << endl << "Enter number for search: ";

    cin >> t;//вводим данных для поиска

    for (int i = 0; i < _j; i++)

    {

        if (_m[i] == t)

        {

            cout << endl << "Was found: " << t;

            //запись

            ofstream st3("D:\\Lab4.dat", ios::binary);

            if (!st3) cout << "File is not open";

            st3.seekp(_j * sizeof(int), ios::beg);//не работает корректно, искажает файл

            st3.write((char*)&_m[i], sizeof(_m[i]));

            st3.close();

        }

    }

}

int main()

{

    int  n = 1, j, l;

    int m[50];

    cout << "Enter quantity of nubers: ";

    cin >> j;

    //запись

    ofstream st1("D:\\Lab4.dat", ios::binary);

    if (!st1) cout << "File is not open";

    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)

    {

        cin >> l;

        n *= l;

        st1.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));

    }

    st1.close();

cout << endl;

    //чтение

    ifstream st2("D:\\Lab4.dat", ios::binary);

    if (!st2) cout << "File is not open";

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)

    {

        st2.read((char*)&m[i], sizeof(m[i]));

        cout << m[i] << endl;

    }

    st2.close();

    find(m, j);

    //чтение

    ifstream st5("D:\\Lab4.dat", ios::binary);

    if (!st5) cout << "File is not open";

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)

    {

        st5.read((char*)&m[i], sizeof(m[i]));

        cout << "\n" << m[i];

    }

    st5.close();

    return 0;

}
```

[image: Вывод]

Знаю что можно сделать так:

ofstream st3("D:\Lab4.dat", iod::app | ios::binary);

но хотел бы узнать почему seekp перезаписывает элементы бинарного файла в 0.
[image: Я пытался перезаписать 2й элемент файла и он не перезаписался, при этом соседние элементы не пострадали. Добавил скрин. Может в С++ перезаписывать в одном файле некоторые элементы (например 2й) нельзя?]

(правка, на самом деле на этом скриншоте все работает так как нужно, дело в том, что 2 * sizeof(int) это третий элемент, а программка перезаписала 6 на 6 и результат не был заметен)
я пытался перезаписать 2й элемент файла и он не перезаписался, при этом соседние элементы не пострадали. Добавил скрин. Может в С++ перезаписывать в одном файле некоторые элементы (например 2й) нельзя?

Например в языке С это делается так (не я писал код). Имеем готовый бинарный файл с числами, записываем числа из файла в массив, находим max и min элементы, а также их позиции в массиве (идентичны с позициями в файле). При помощи функции fseek перемещаем курсор на нужную позицию и перезаписываем элемент файла на этой позиции. Программа меняет местами max и min элементы. Эту программку я хочу сделать в C++. Как я понял, программка не перезаписывает весь файл из массива.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Работает, заменил 2й элемент бинарного файла.

Через fstream выглядит грамотнее. Спасибо Harry.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне вот интересно, как так можно умудриться скопировать код, что после каждой строчки добавляется пустая строка... я без претензий, просто не первый раз вижу — действительно интересно из-за чего так получается... или это люди действительно так пишут?

Comment: Впервые вижу код c++, кто вы такой?

Comment: я скопировал из компилятора, вставил сюда, вылезло сообщение что написано неправильно, вижу в черновике нет переносов текста на новую строку, ну вот я и в конце каждой строки ввел Enter. Получилось. Задаю тут вопрос в первый раз.

Comment: @MartyMcFly... мм... значит это просто кривое сообщение сайта... скорей всего подразумевалось, что надо отформатировать код, с помощью отступов или трёх бектиков (```)... это можно сделать кнопкой со скобками `{}` или `Ctrl-K`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ofstream st3("D:\\Lab4.dat", ios::binary);
```

Открыли файл **для перезаписи**

```
        st3.seekp(_j * sizeof(int),ios::beg);
```

Перешли в **новом пустом файле** на новую позицию. Вот такая вот фигня получилась...

Я бы открывал как

```
fstream st3("D:\\Lab4.dat", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
```

Вот тестовая программка, которая меняет значения в файле - при этом и читая, и записывая.

```
const char * filename = "data";

void read()
{
    ifstream in(filename,ios::binary);
    for(int n;in.read((char*)&n,sizeof(int));)
        cout << n << " ";
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    {
        ofstream out(filename,ios::binary);
        for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
            out.write((const char*)&n,sizeof(int));
    }
    read();
    {
        fstream f(filename,ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
        for(int m, n = 0; n < 10; n+=3)
        {
            f.seekg(n*sizeof(int));
            f.read((char*)&m,sizeof(int));
            m *= m;
            f.seekp(n*sizeof(int));
            f.write((const char*)&m,sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    read();
}
```

Результат работы:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 9 4 5 36 7 8 81
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я понял что происходила перезапись пройденных элементов функцией seekp если открыть файл через ofstream, но в таком случае как перезаписать например 2й элемент файла используя сдвиг курсора seekp. Знаю, что можно написать код который сделает эту перезапись, но я хотел бы это сделать максимально кратко. Например в языке С перезаписать например только 2й элемент можно использовав для  сдвига курсора функцию fseek. То же самое я хотел бы сделать в С++.

Comment: @MartyMcFly, чтобы при открытии файла на запись его содержимое не уничтожалось, нужно открывать его в режиме `ios::in|ios::out`, т.е. в твоём случае будет достаточно указать `ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out`. при этом `ofstream` сам добавляет `ios::out`, так что его указывать не обязательно, хотя и желательно ради уменьшения конфуза...

Comment: Я не понял - я же написал, как заменить строку так, чтобы файл не перезаписывался? Если вы считаете свой код максимально кратким - то от моего исправления он длиннее не становится :)

Comment: Да, я сделал так как вы сказали и  получилось записать нужный элемент в конец файла без перезаписи предыдущих элементов, но я хочу перезаписать 2й элемент файла и он не перезаписывается подобным образом. Добавил скрин. Может в С++ перезаписывать в одном файле некоторые элементы  (например 2й) без перезаписи соседних нельзя?

Comment: Запутали окончательно. Какой `ofstream` с флагом `ios::in`? Вы пишете какой-то свой код, и предъявляете претензии :) Если напишете так, как я вам сказал в своем ответе, и не будет работать - будем смотреть.

Comment: Я решил задать вопрос потому что сам много часов комбинировал синтаксис, потом долго гуглил, все писали одно и то-же, но не получалось перезаписать только один элемент (например 2й). Ладно все, остановимся на этом. Буду выносить элементы файла в массив, там их сортировать, а потом перезаписывать.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Harry, т.к. про `ios::in` я заикнулся, то уточню: с `ios::app` возможна запись только в конец файла, это контролируется на уровне ОС (по крайней мере для *nix-систем). Все seek'и в таком потоке будут игнорироваться... на сколько я понял, OP хочет изменять бинарный файл в произвольном месте без перезаписи — для этого нужно открыть его с `ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out`, но для `ofstream` явно указывать `ios::out` не обязательно, поэтому всё правильно: надо открыть `ofstream` с флагом `ios::in` (ну и `ios::binary`)...

Comment: Работает, спасибо Fat-Zer

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну, я работаю в Windows, там мой код вполне работал... Век живи - век учись :)

Comment: @Harry, гмм... не верю... с `ios:app` все данные должны всегда писаться в конец файла, как если бы перед этим выполнялось `fs.seekp(0, ios::end)`... msvc, конечно, славится своей вольной интерпретацией стандартов, но я почти уверен, что это там тоже так... я, правда, не знаю поддерживается ли это в win на уровне ОС (хотя скорей всего это так), чтобы при конкурентной записи данные также не терялись, или это делается исключительно средствами msvcrt...

Comment: Я добавил скрин с результатом, в конце своего вопроса.(с телефона на скрин есть только ссылка, но с ПК скрин отображался.)

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, что-то не то. Изменяю свой ответ. Или я прошлый раз не тот текст скопировал?...